# elastic search query not returning results when the field has double quotes

Tags: elasticsearch

I execute this query

```
POST /_search {
  "query":{
    "filtered":{
      "filter":{
        "bool":{
          "must":[
            {
              "term":{
                "tpid":3
              }
            },
            {
              "term":{
                "eapid":0
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get result like this

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 20,
    "successful": 20,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 10633,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "gss.aggregated.se.logstash-2014.11.04",
        "_type": "gss.aggregated.se",
        "_id": "v63uksmIRgG9bI5hgS5DIQ",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "blacklistAggregatedKey": {
            "utcTimestamp": "2014-10-28T09:00",
            "departureAirport": "OVB",
            "arrivalAirport": "KRR",
            "tpid": 3,
            "eapid": 0,
            "AdvancePurchaseWindow": 3,
            "LengthOfStay": -1
          },
          "blacklistAggregatedValue": {
            "searchCount": 1,
            "blackListed": 0
          },
          "@version": "1",
          "@timestamp": "2014-11-04T19:30:16.426Z",
          "type": "gss.aggregated.se"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "gss.aggregated.se.logstash-2014.11.04",
        "_type": "gss.aggregated.se",
        "_id": "bu7I38_CRDG17sXVq3IR-g",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "blacklistAggregatedKey": {
            "utcTimestamp": "2014-10-28T09:00",
            "departureAirport": "OSL",
            "arrivalAirport": "OSA",
            "tpid": 3,
            "eapid": 0,
            "AdvancePurchaseWindow": 149,
            "LengthOfStay": -1
          },
          "blacklistAggregatedValue": {
            "searchCount": 1,
            "blackListed": 0
          },
          "@version": "1",
          "@timestamp": "2014-11-04T19:30:16.486Z",
          "type": "gss.aggregated.se"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "gss.aggregated.se.logstash-2014.11.04",
        "_type": "gss.aggregated.se",
        "_id": "wWb9xFpuRASTWyaqm-q9Kw",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "blacklistAggregatedKey": {
            "utcTimestamp": "2014-10-28T09:00",
            "departureAirport": "OSL",
            "arrivalAirport": "NYC",
            "tpid": 3,
            "eapid": 0,
            "AdvancePurchaseWindow": 49,
            "LengthOfStay": -1
          },
          "blacklistAggregatedValue": {
            "searchCount": 1,
            "blackListed": 0
          },
          "@version": "1",
          "@timestamp": "2014-11-04T19:30:16.491Z",
          "type": "gss.aggregated.se"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "gss.aggregated.se.logstash-2014.11.04",
        "_type": "gss.aggregated.se",
        "_id": "c1ULKWyhR0iYmaZ5unafKA",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "blacklistAggregatedKey": {
            "utcTimestamp": "2014-10-28T09:00",
            "departureAirport": "OSL",
            "arrivalAirport": "MOW",
            "tpid": 3,
            "eapid": 0,
            "AdvancePurchaseWindow": 16,
            "LengthOfStay": -1
          },
          "blacklistAggregatedValue": {
            "searchCount": 1,
            "blackListed": 0
          },
          "@version": "1",
          "@timestamp": "2014-11-04T19:30:16.495Z",
          "type": "gss.aggregated.se"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "gss.aggregated.se.logstash-2014.11.04",
        "_type": "gss.aggregated.se",
        "_id": "BGuGnuXsSne6jB7_ith5Lg",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "blacklistAggregatedKey": {
            "utcTimestamp": "2014-10-28T09:00",
            "departureAirport": "OSL",
            "arrivalAirport": "MEL",
            "tpid": 3,
            "eapid": 0,
            "AdvancePurchaseWindow": 10,
            "LengthOfStay": -1
          },
          "blacklistAggregatedValue": {
            "searchCount": 2,
            "blackListed": 0
          },
          "@version": "1",
          "@timestamp": "2014-11-04T19:30:16.505Z",
          "type": "gss.aggregated.se"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "gss.aggregated.se.logstash-2014.11.04",
        "_type": "gss.aggregated.se",
        "_id": "lHXm68TTTPG44dIskGCr-w",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "blacklistAggregatedKey": {
            "utcTimestamp": "2014-10-28T09:00",
            "departureAirport": "OSA",
            "arrivalAirport": "STO",
            "tpid": 3,
            "eapid": 0,
            "AdvancePurchaseWindow": 12,
            "LengthOfStay": -1
          },
          "blacklistAggregatedValue": {
            "searchCount": 1,
            "blackListed": 0
          },
          "@version": "1",
          "@timestamp": "2014-11-04T19:30:16.606Z",
          "type": "gss.aggregated.se"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "gss.aggregated.se.logstash-2014.11.04",
        "_type": "gss.aggregated.se",
        "_id": "DewbkMq0Q22IsReLTRIXww",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "blacklistAggregatedKey": {
            "utcTimestamp": "2014-10-28T09:00",
            "departureAirport": "OSA",
            "arrivalAirport": "NYC",
            "tpid": 3,
            "eapid": 0,
            "AdvancePurchaseWindow": 3,
            "LengthOfStay": -1
          },
          "blacklistAggregatedValue": {
            "searchCount": 1,
            "blackListed": 0
          },
          "@version": "1",
          "@timestamp": "2014-11-04T19:30:16.623Z",
          "type": "gss.aggregated.se"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "gss.aggregated.se.logstash-2014.11.04",
        "_type": "gss.aggregated.se",
        "_id": "tuCl1rEcT4W3dJ9Am-XvSw",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "blacklistAggregatedKey": {
            "utcTimestamp": "2014-10-28T09:00",
            "departureAirport": "OSA",
            "arrivalAirport": "MEL",
            "tpid": 3,
            "eapid": 0,
            "AdvancePurchaseWindow": 9,
            "LengthOfStay": 30
          },
          "blacklistAggregatedValue": {
            "searchCount": 25,
            "blackListed": 0
          },
          "@version": "1",
          "@timestamp": "2014-11-04T19:30:16.625Z",
          "type": "gss.aggregated.se"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "gss.aggregated.se.logstash-2014.11.04",
        "_type": "gss.aggregated.se",
        "_id": "6-O9T3HuRYuSVD68_cVeCg",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "blacklistAggregatedKey": {
            "utcTimestamp": "2014-10-28T09:00",
            "departureAirport": "OKC",
            "arrivalAirport": "PHX",
            "tpid": 3,
            "eapid": 0,
            "AdvancePurchaseWindow": 126,
            "LengthOfStay": 7
          },
          "blacklistAggregatedValue": {
            "searchCount": 1,
            "blackListed": 0
          },
          "@version": "1",
          "@timestamp": "2014-11-04T19:30:16.787Z",
          "type": "gss.aggregated.se"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "gss.aggregated.se.logstash-2014.11.04",
        "_type": "gss.aggregated.se",
        "_id": "5_bGAZxdRIy5kAR5XuV70A",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "blacklistAggregatedKey": {
            "utcTimestamp": "2014-10-28T09:00",
            "departureAirport": "NYC",
            "arrivalAirport": "QLA",
            "tpid": 3,
            "eapid": 0,
            "AdvancePurchaseWindow": 11,
            "LengthOfStay": -1
          },
          "blacklistAggregatedValue": {
            "searchCount": 1,
            "blackListed": 0
          },
          "@version": "1",
          "@timestamp": "2014-11-04T19:30:16.862Z",
          "type": "gss.aggregated.se"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to filter this further by departure airport. when I try

```
POST /_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "tpid": 3
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "eapid": 0
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "departureAirport": "\"OVB\""
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't get results back.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

Mention the mapping that you used? Run `GET _mapping` to get that. That will help debug the issue.

But my hunch is that this is an analyzer issue. The field `departureAirport` must have been analyzed such that the double inverted quotes in its values got stripped off during indexing. This is the default behaviour. What I mean to say is, the field `departureAirport` has value "OVB" (without the quotes) indexed and not "\"OVB\"" (with the quotes). That is why you do not get results with the value having quotes.

Comment: Thank you Mouzer for replying.
I initially tried it without the double quotes..I didnt get results hence this attempt.
POST /_search { "query": { "filtered":{ "filter": { "bool": { "must" : [ { "term" : { "tpid" : 3 } }, { "term" : { "eapid" : 0 } }, {"term": { "departureAirport": "OVB"} }

                ]

            }
        }

    }
}
}